Is there a way to execute commands from a .cmd file on zsh shell (Mac/Unix)
I am in the directory of the file that I am attempting to execute and I know I am using the proper text to execute the file given being in the right location. The file is named 'modify-search.cmd' and I am executing:
./modify-search.cmd

However, because zsh only recognizes 'echo', the other commands in my ".cmd" file aren't being recognized and therefore my zsh shell states "command not found". Here is the code from my modify-search.cmd file, minus the user specific domain/URL and admin key
@echo off

rem Set values for your Search service
set url=YOUR_SEARCH_URL
set admin_key=YOUR_ADMIN_KEY

echo -----
echo Updating the skillset...
call curl -X PUT %url%/skillsets/margies-skillset?api-version=2020-06-30 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-key: %admin_key%" -d @skillset.json

rem wait
timeout /t 2 /nobreak

echo -----
echo Updating the index...
call curl -X PUT %url%/indexes/margies-index?api-version=2020-06-30 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-key: %admin_key%" -d @index.json

rem wait
timeout /t 2 /nobreak

echo -----
echo Updating the indexer...
call curl -X PUT %url%/indexers/margies-indexer?api-version=2020-06-30 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-key: %admin_key%" -d @indexer.json

echo -----
echo Resetting the indexer
call curl -X POST %url%/indexers/margies-indexer/reset?api-version=2020-06-30 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "api-key: %admin_key%" 

rem wait
timeout /t 5 /nobreak

echo -----
echo Rerunning the indexer
call curl -X POST %url%/indexers/margies-indexer/run?api-version=2020-06-30 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "api-key: %admin_key%" 



Here is the output I'm getting in the terminal when I execute the command:
./modify-search.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 3: rem: command not found
-----
Updating the skillset...
./modify-search.cmd: line 9: call: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 11: rem: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 12: timeout: command not found
-----
Updating the index...
./modify-search.cmd: line 16: call: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 18: rem: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 19: timeout: command not found
-----
Updating the indexer...
./modify-search.cmd: line 23: call: command not found
-----
Resetting the indexer
./modify-search.cmd: line 27: call: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 29: rem: command not found
./modify-search.cmd: line 30: timeout: command not found
-----
Rerunning the indexer
./modify-search.cmd: line 34: call: command not found

This makes sense to me since echo is a built-in command in zsh, hence @echo not being executed but the notification text messages being executed. How do I get these other '.cmd' commands to execute?
I'm doing training labs for Microsoft Azure so I'm using the Azure CLI and I'm doing all of this through Visual Studio code. Additionally, I installed a Powershell extension onto my Visual Studio code and I can't get it to work there either. Upon activating Powershell (via zsh), I tried to execute:
command ./modify-search.cmd

That command got me the same output as my executable command on zsh - the 'echo' statements worked and every other command returned "command not found".
My inefficient workaround to get through the lab exercise has been to plug in my URL and admin key in the '.cmd' code directly, wherever my file has:

%url% %admin_key%

and execute the calls directly through my zsh shell (plugged into my Azure CLI), which worked the last time i encountered this issue.
This is my second time running across this problem so I figured I would ask for help so I could have a more efficient solution going forward. Help, please, any one?
Edit: Update, my work around doesn't work this time! Last time I was executing Azure CLI commands and substituting my authentication data to connect to my account in between those designated sections. This time, I'm executing POST and PUT statements and it's not working the same. I get the following output:
zsh: no matches found: %url%/skillsets/margies-skillset?api-version=2020-06-30

Edit2: Okay so I'm attempting to call a REST API using VS Code, which some of you may have noticed from the code of the modify-search.cmd. I am doing some research related to it and that may lead me to the solution. So far, I've:

Installed the REST Client extension for my IDE, VS Code

made a separate '.rest' file without extensions (so that the text file can change the code to a '.rest' file thereafter).


I attempted to send the request but I'm getting a getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND echo error... progress

That .cmd file is specifically for Windows. It is executed by the Windows command line interpreter. It is not a PowerShell script, so that won't help. None of it (other than the ECHO) is compatible with a Mac.

Thank you sir! That adds some clarity to what I was seeing. I just realized that I am attempting to call REST API from my IDE (VS Code). Sorry, just made a 2nd edit clarifying this. Is it reasonable to believe that the command would be executed in the Microsoft server where I'm sending the request and therefore those commands would work, if sent?

Sorry, but I don't know the answer to that question.

The code you posted looks like a Windows batch program; I'm not fluent enough to see whether it would also happen to be valid in Powershell, but since you tagged the question with powershell, you probably already suspect that it is. In this case, you could be lucky, because there seems to be an implementation of powershell for the Mac.

@user1934428 thank you sir, yes, I actually referenced that link to install Powershell. Thank you for your input!

As noted in the comments .cmd (or .bat) files are so-called batch files that use the language of the legacy Windows shell (a.k.a. command-line interpreter), cmd.exe.
As such, you cannot run batch files on Unix-like platforms, such as macOS.
However, it isn't hard to translate your batch file into a shell script that the POSIX-compatible zsh shell understands:

Remove @echo off

Replace rem with #

Remove set  from variable definitions such as set url=YOUR_SEARCH_URL

Reference variables with prefix $ rather than enclosing them in %...%; e.g., use $url instead of %url%

Remove call  before calling utilities such as curl

Replace timeout /t 5 /nobreak with sleep 5 (and analogously for other seconds values).


For a juxtaposition of fundamental shell-language features in cmd.exe, POSIX-compatible shells, and PowerShell, see this answer.

As also noted in the comments, a cross-platform solution is possible, given that the .NET (Core)-based edition of PowerShell, PowerShell (Core) 7, is cross-platform and runs on Unix-like platforms too.
That is, if you write your code in PowerShell and put it in a .ps1 file, it will run on all supported platforms (though platform differences must situationally still be respected, such as not using .exe extensions in utility calls on Unix and platform-specific environment variables)

Just a nit, I'd call cmd a "shell" just to be consistent in language for what kind of tool it is akin to zsh, powershell, et al.

@mklement0, a perfectly correct answer, as always. I would recommend that the OP ignore everything except the last two (2) paragraphs. Write the code once in PowerShell and run on all supported platforms. Creating YAMS (Yet Another Mutant Script) multiplies both the work and maintenance effort.

Agreed, @lit, at least in the long term (learning PowerShell is a nontrivial undertaking, though, as we both know, ultimately well worth the effort); thanks for the nice feedback.

I reviewed the answer you (mklement0) referred me to, and now my script works! I'm running into new problems unrelated to the post (this is my 'welcome to the world of learning to program' moment), but the script works because I'm getting a new error message in my zsh shell stating "curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname". which suggests to me that I'm having IAM issues with my API... I got a HTTP error 403 so I upgraded my API resource to admin-level permissions (I know, not wise, it's temporary) and still couldn't get the URL to load - now I get HTTP Error 401. I'll figure that out! Thank you!

And for clarity, I took your input on translating my batch file into a shell script, and ran it as a '.sh' file. I did refer to the linked answer for the juxtaposition of fundamental shell-language and I rewrote the script in Powershell using the environmental & local variables but I did that after my brain was fried and I remembered that the script was no longer problematic but making my script access/call the API with permission was the new problem. So like I said, your solution did work! I just stumbled upon a new problem, separate from the original question asked.
